# multiple classes in container_class of wp_nav_menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

i am using **wordpress** with *twitter bootstrap* in which trying to design a **navigation menu**...

I have called `wp_nav_menu` and inside it i have defined its related parameters mentioned in [Function Reference/wp nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)...

What i am trying to do is adding multiple classes to container menu for example:-

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'menu_class' => 'class1 class2 class3', 
    'container_class' => 'nav-collapse collapse',
) );
```

It doesnot work at all, browser shows `menu-menu-container` class on `container_class` indeed...

What may be the trick to make it work? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress **extends** the menu class names by default:

> ... class="menu-'. $menu->slug .'-container"';

Source: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L202

You could use your own **walker class**. It doesn’t actually ‘do’ (in the sense of generating HTML) anything. It simply traces each branch of your tree: it has to be extended by other classes which tell it what to do for each element it comes across.

WordPress provides its own extending classes, such as:

- `Walker_Nav_Menu` – for displaying the HTML for navigation menus
- `Walker_Page` – for displaying a list of pages
- `Walker_Category` – for displaying a list of taxonomy terms.

Example:

```
$walker = new Custom_Walker_Menu();

wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'menu_class' => 'class1 class2 class3', 
    'container_class' => 'nav-collapse collapse',
    'walker' => $walker
) );
```

Please read the reference: [**Class Reference/Walker**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker).

There are many custom WordPress nav walker classes to implement, check this [repository](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker).